# Python: How to subtract the first number in a list with the second number

Tags: python, list

So I've looked everywhere and I cannot find the answer for this anywhere.

So I'm trying to subtract a list of numbers like [1, 2, 3] = -4 cause 1-2-3 = -4.

I was trying to use slices of lists to accomplish this but I just can't figure this out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming length of list > 0:

```
>>> s = [1, 2, 3]
>>> s[0] - sum(s[1:])
-4
```

General Case:

```
if len(s) > 0:
   return s[0] - sum(s[1:])
else:
   return None
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Can't believe I couldn't figure it out haha

Answer (score 0):

alternatively you could use the `reduce` builtin

```
>>> s = [1,2,3]
>>> reduce(lambda x,y : x-y, s, None)
-4
```

Comment: Not sure what any of that means, but I'm sure I'll find out some day haha